# PHP 5.3.3 fails to validate XML against nested XSD's

Tags: php, xml, xsd, libxml2

After upgrading from PHP 5.2.8 to 5.3.3, the new `libxml_disable_entity_loader(false)` function does not seem to work on Windows via command line to a PHP file on a network share. More specifically, `DOMDocument::schemaValidate()` fails with XSD files that contain multiple levels of nested include()'s to other XSD files on a network share.

The example below leads me to believe that the function call to `libxml_disable_entity_loader(false)` is not being honored in PHP with XSD files that contain multiple levels of nested XSD include()'s.

Am I missing something here or do you think this is a bug with PHP or possibly libxml?

**TO REPLICATE:**

**Test 1 (success):**

```
"C:\PHP\5.3.3\php.exe" -c "C:\PHP\5.3.3\php.ini" "C:\Temp\validate.php"
```

- The Windows command line example above uses a hard coded path and not a Windows shared folder.
- It will successfully echo "passed" in both PHP 5.2.8 and PHP 5.3.3.

**Test 2 (fail):**

```
"C:\PHP\5.3.3\php.exe" -c "C:\PHP\5.3.3\php.ini" "\\192.168.82.99\Deployment\Temp\validate.php"
```

- Right-click on your C: drive > Properties > Sharing > New Share > Share name: "Deployment"
- Edit the IP address in the command line example above to match your local machine.
- The Windows command line example above uses the same files but through a Windows shared folder.
- In PHP 5.2.8, it will echo "passed".
- In PHP 5.3.3, it will echo "failed" and produce the following PHP Warnings about "failed to load external entity" and "Failed to load the document":

*Running the above command line example in PHP 5.3.3 produces:*

```
Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/192.168.82.99/DEPLOYMENT/Temp/grandparent.xsd" in \\192.168.82.99\DEPLOYMENT\Temp\validate.php on line 8
Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}include': Failed to load the document '/192.168.82.99/DEPLOYMENT/Temp/grandparent.xsd' for inclusion. in \\192.168.82.99\DEPLOYMENT\Temp\validate.php on line 8
Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema in \\192.168.82.99\DEPLOYMENT\Temp\validate.php on line 8
failed
```

**FILES NEEDED TO REPLICATE:**

*Place all these files in* "C:\Temp\" (*or change your paths in the command line examples*)

**validate.php**

```
<?php
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);

$xmlDoc = new DomDocument();
$xmlDoc->load('sample.xml');

echo $xmlDoc->schemaValidate('child.xsd') ? 'passed' : 'failed'; 
?>
```

**sample.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<team mascot="cowboys" />
```

**child.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified" >
  <!-- The include below works -->
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="parent.xsd" />
  <xsd:element name="team" type="baseTeam" />
</xsd:schema>
```

**parent.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified" >
  <!-- The include below fails in PHP 5.3.3 even though libxml_disable_entity_loader(false) is called! -->
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="grandparent.xsd" />
  <xsd:complexType name="baseTeam">
     <xsd:attribute name="mascot" type="mascotNames" use="required" />
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**grandparent.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified" >
  <xsd:simpleType name="mascotNames">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="bengals" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="cowboys" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="patriots" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: This is probably libxml2 related, not a problem of PHP itself. Try to use the same libxml version in both PHP 5.2 and 5.3. If the problem persists, [submit a bug report](http://bugs.php.net/).

Comment: Works fine for me using php 5.3.3/winxp/php.net-build.

Answer (score 2):

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/sources/';
$file = $dir . 'data.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($file);

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->documentURI = $file;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$doc->xinclude();

echo $doc->schemaValidate($dir . 'child.xsd') ? 'passed' : 'failed';
```